# How can I configure gmail in nagios core for sending email notification?

Tags: nagios

Configured nagios but cant get a  valid information for configuring gmail,Used sstmp but not working can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search found this:

http://www.unixmen.com/send-alerts-nagios-core-using-gmail-yahoo/